# How can I get the frequency and its percentage in the same row as alphabet and sub alphabet?

Tags: python

I want to get the frequency and its percentage in the same row as alphabet and sub alphabet.

I have a `.csv` file as follows:

| Alphabet | Sub alphabet | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 |
| A | C | 1 |
| A | E | 2 |
| A | F | 3 |
| D | B | 1 |
| D | C | 2 |
| D | E | 2 |
| D | F | 3 |

I want it to return result like this:

| Alphabet | Value | Frequency | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 50% |
| A | 2 | 1 | 25% |
| A | 3 | 1 | 25% |
| D | 1 | 1 | 25% |
| D | 2 | 2 | 50% |
| D | 3 | 1 | 25% |

Believably expected table above is self-explanatory. The percentage refers to the corresponding row's frequency divided by total frequency.

My code:

```
import csv

with open("/Users/name/Desktop/path/alphabetical_list.csv") as alphabetical_list_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(alphabetical_list_file, delimiter=',')
```

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

How can I get the frequency and its percentage? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```py
import csv
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

with open("data.csv", "r") as fin,\
     open("result.csv", "w") as fout:
    next(fin)  # Skip header row
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    writer.writerow(["Alphabet", "Value", "Frequency", "%"])  # Write header
    for key, group in groupby(csv.reader(fin), key=itemgetter(0)):
        frequencies = Counter(map(itemgetter(2), group))
        total = 100 / sum(frequencies.values())
        writer.writerows(
            [key, value, frequency, frequency * total]
            for value, frequency in frequencies.items()
        )
```

Assumptions:

- `data.csv` is the input file. Its first row contains the headers.
- The first column comes in groups.

Result for sample `data.csv`

```
Alphabet,Sub alphabet,Value
A,B,1
A,C,1
A,E,2
A,F,3
D,B,1
D,C,2
D,E,2
D,F,3
```

is

```
Alphabet,Value,Frequency,%
A,1,2,50.0
A,2,1,25.0
A,3,1,25.0
D,1,1,25.0
D,2,2,50.0
D,3,1,25.0
```

You could also use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = df.groupby(["Alphabet", "Value"], as_index=False).agg(Frequency=("Value", "count"))
df["%"] = df["Frequency"] / df.groupby("Alphabet")["Frequency"].transform("sum") * 100
df.to_csv("result.csv", index=None)
```

- First [group](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the dataframe `df` by the columns `Alphabet` and `Value`, count the number of items in each group, and name the resulting new column `Frequency` via [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html).
- Then add a new column by normalising `Frequency` for each `Alphabet` group: group `df` by `Alphabet`, get column `Frequency`, and sum the values. The [`.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) makes sure that the result keeps its original shape. Then divide the `Frequency` column by the result.
- Finally write `df` into a csv-file, without the indices.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! Your answer code works! Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, I'm new to pandas, can you explain what your pandas code means?

Comment: @MyCar I've added some explanations and hope they help. (A bit generic, but there are only a handful of Pandas techniques that you have to learn to get the full value out of the library. Among them are `groupby` in combination with `agg` and `transform`.)